# f string formatting: Invalid format Specifier

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass the following data into POST request:

```
data = {
    "To": MY_PHONE_NUMBER,
    "From": TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
    "Parameters": f'{"appointment_time":{apointment_time}, "name":{name_var}, "age":{age_var}}',
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Parameters": f'{"appointment_time":{apointment_time}, "name":{name_var}, "age":{age_var}}',
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

I've tried using .format as well with no luck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In an f string it interprets the brace as preceding a variable. The braces you included for formatting are confusing the parser. Use two braces to escape it.

```
"Parameters": f'{{"appointment_time":{apointment_time}, "name": {name_var}, "age":{age_var}}}'
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra `}` character at the end of your code near ``age_var` variable:

```
"Parameters": f'{"appointment_time":{apointment_time}, "name":{name_var}, "age":{age_var}}',
```

It should be:

```
"Parameters": f'{"appointment_time":{apointment_time}, "name":{name_var}, "age":{age_var}',
```

You should remove it to work.